# NSLinguisticTagger Language is "und"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to figure out the language of a string. If I pass it on from a variable it recognises the language as "und" but if I pass it on as

```
 [tagger setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Example 2 Three people have attached a rope around your belly and pull it with the indicated forces. The sketch isn’t true to scale and shows the situation froth above. a) Detennine with a drawing, in what direction you are pulled (assuming that you don’t put up any resistance) Choose a scale of l00N 2 Ion . b) What is the inﬂuence of the lengths of the ropes?"]];
```

it recognises the language correctly. The text is the same in both cases

```
//Recognize Language for Output
{
    NSArray *tagschemes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage, nil];
    NSLinguisticTagger *tagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:tagschemes options:0];
    [tagger setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text]];

    NSString *language = [tagger tagAtIndex:0 scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage tokenRange:NULL sentenceRange:NULL];

    output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The language is %@\rand the following words were found:\r\r%@", language, output];

}
```

What kind of language is "und" and why doesn't it recoginze the language correctly as en?

Comment: are you 100% sure [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text] is resolving to not nil

Comment: Yes, if it would be resolving to nil the output would be (null) as well.

Comment: Can you show a complete self-contained example of the "non-working case"? - I have tested your code with `[tagger setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text]]` where `text` is your string, and tagger recognized the language "en" correctly.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the formatting of the string I used. As soon as I removed the line breaks it worked fine. Do you think this is a bug? And if so how do I tell Apple about it? Sorry for the question, but I'm new to pretty much everything code related.

Comment: You’re over-using -stringWithFormat:, by the way. There are two redundant uses up above, one of which is actually quite dangerous.

Comment: Raise a bug at bugreport.apple.com with your dev account. NSLinguisticTagger has a youthful personality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOrthography_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOrthography) for NSOrthography:

**the tag `und` is used if a specific language cannot be determined.**

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't catch that while looking through the documents.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the text wasn't formatted properly. The original text in the "text" string looked like this:

```
2014-01-28 18:13:51.412 Tesseract[35357:70b] Old text: Example 2

Three people have attached a rope around your belly

and pull it with the indicated forces. The sketch isn’t

true to scale and shows the situation from above.

a) Detennine with a drawing, in what direction you are
pulled (assuming that you don’t put up any resistance)
Choose a scale of l00N 2 tom .

b) What is the influence of the lengths of the ropes?
```

If the text is reformatted using

```
text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
```

it looks like this and NSLinguisticTagger will recognise the language correctly.

```
2014-01-28 18:13:51.412 Tesseract[35357:70b] Reformatted text: Example 2  Three people have attached a rope around your belly  and pull it with the indicated forces. The sketch isn’t  true to scale and shows the situation from above.  a) Detennine with a drawing, in what direction you are pulled (assuming that you don’t put up any resistance) Choose a scale of l00N 2 tom .  b) What is the influence of the lengths of the ropes?
```